# How else can we write a - (a - b)?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

What is a - (a - b) equal to? How do you pull those terms out of the brackets?

I though of these, and I'm not convinced they're correct:

a + (-a + b)

a - (a + (-b) )

a - a + (-b) (hey, wait...)

Comment: Note that $-(a-b)=b-a$ so that $a-(a-b)=a+[-(a-b)]=a+[b-a]=a+b-a$

Comment: @MarkBennet, you should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$a-(a-b) = a+(-1)(a+(-1)b)$$
$$= a+(-1)a+(-1)(-1)b $$
$$=a-a+(1)b$$
$$=0+b$$
$$=b$$

Answer (score 4):

As requested comment has become answer

Note that $−(a−b)=b−a$

so that $a−(a−b)=a+[−(a−b)]=a+[b−a]=a+b−a$

The general rules for dealing with signs seem very obvious once they are known, but can prove tricky when you are learning them. My answer above brought in a $+$ sign and some extra brackets. Here is a different way of looking at things, choosing only very simple [and, I hope, obvious] manipulations.

The most basic rule for the negative of an expression $x$, which can be use to check the arithmetic, is that $x-x=0$. If we then substitute $(a-b)$ for $x$, we know that $$(a-b)-(a-b)=0$$ or $$a-b-(a-b)=0$$ If we add $b$ to both sides we get $$a-(a-b)=b$$ which gets a useful answer immediately. If we further subtract $a$ from both sides we obtain $$-(a-b)=b-a$$ which is the identity I quoted.

Comment: Nice answer and a different way of looking at it.